# K8s matrices, Top node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to select the first node that has the most CPU usage, I run the following but I need the first node without manipulating the output itself

```
Kubectl top node --sort-by='{.spec.status.capacity.cpu}'
```

this gives me all the nodes sorted
I'm thinking about something like in SQL

```
kubectl top 1 node --sort-by='{.spec.status.capacity.cpu}'
```

any Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kubectl doesn't provide built in option to get only one node using top command but you can achieve it using simple shell command (if your are running in linux/Mac based system) like below

```
kubectl top node --sort-by=cpu --no-headers | head -1
```

The above command works if your kubectl version is 1.18 (or greater).

If your kubectl version is less than 1.18 version then sort command in top will return inconsistent response due to [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81270), in this case you can use below command to make it work.

```
kubectl top node --no-headers | sort -k3 -n | tail -1
```

Comment: how to get the node name only?

Comment: kubectl top nodes --sort-by='cpu' --no-headers | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'  - This should get you the first node name alone.